# Is this the character 良?

Tags: characters, character-identification, seal

Someone sent me this picture and asked me if I knew what it was:

[image: pic]

I had a couple of hunches and browsed through Pleco's **Small Seal Script Chinese character font**. The small seal script for 良 looks very similar:

> [image: pic]

But I'm not expert & there might be some rookie mistake I'm making here.

Is it the picture *actually* the character 良 -or- have I somehow lost the plot here on this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is「良」.

[image]

That's just a minor shape variation, probably influenced by Qin bamboo or Han clerical brush writing.

[image]

> In small seal script, the bottom of「良」is corrupted into「亾」(「亡」), so as long as you see something resembling「亾」then that's a positive identification.